# Github pages custom domain is showing "improperly configured"

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, namecheap

I bought `domain.name` from namecheap and configured a custom domain in github pages using the instructions [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages#using-an-apex-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)

**Issue 1:**

Github pages settings is showing that "DNS valid for primary" and "domain.name is improperly configured"

**Issue 2:**

Following redirects are working:

`domain.name -> https://www.domain.name/`

`www.domain.name -> https://www.domain.name/`

`http://www.domain.name/ -> https://www.domain.name/`

But following are not:

`https://domain.name -> This site can't be reached`

`http://domain.name -> Fastly error: unknown domain: domain.name. Please check that this domain has been added to a service. Details: cache-bom4736-BOM`

**My github pages settings:**

Custom domain: `www.domain.name`

**DNS settings in namecheap**

CNAME record:
`www -> <github-username>.github.io`

A records:

`@ -> 185.199.108.153`

`@ -> 185.199.109.153`

`@ -> 185.199.110.153`

`@ -> 185.199.111.153`